# SSRS standalone formulas

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been working on this for days without being able to solve yet.  It's probably simple if you know what you're doing. I'm simply trying to make a standalone formula that is not in a tablix or anything, it's just in a textbox.

Here is an example of my Dataset called Dataset1:

[image]

What I am trying to get is a sum of the Actual Cost when the Category is Labor from Dataset1. My current expression is:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Category.Value="Labor", Fields!ActualCost.Value, 0), "Dataset1")
```

I refer to Dataset1 as my scope because otherwise, I get an error about using an aggregate expression without a scope.

The report runs but shows #Error in the textbox that has my expression in it.  When I replace Fields!ActualCost.Value with a 1, I get the answer, 5, which is the correct number of rows with Labor as the Category.  But it won't let me sum the numbers in the ActualCost column where Category is Labor.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I feel like it's something to do with aggregating, but I'm not sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Since posting this, I figured out that putting "nothing" instead of 0 in the expression gives the right result.  So I'm not totally sure what that means.  I guess there is a datatype issue or something.  Anybody know what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with the datatype of fields!ActualCost.Value. If that field is a decimal (regardless of how you have it formatted), try using cdec(0) instead of just 0 in your expression.

Comment: Great!  I replaced nothing with cdec(0) in my expressions, and they still work.  I guess 0 is considered an integer and cannot be added to a decimal?

Comment: Yep. You can't sum mixed data types.